# Android: Seekbar doesn't scroll all the way to end

Tags: android, seekbar

Hi  I have a seekbar in my app that i need to snap to 7 positions.  To achieve this I set the max property of the Seekbar to 7.  NOw, to be aesthetically pleasing, i need to be able to drag my seekbar all the way to end of the bar, but when I set a value to the max property, the scroll won't drag all the way to end.  Why does this happen and how can I get around it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try adding some padding to the sides of your seekbar

Comment: that actually did work i guess my fingers were too big for it register my finger in the last position.