# SeekBar customization - how to properly position custom "thumb" image?

Tags: android, seekbar

I have customised my SeekBar - I use a custom image as the background, and a custom image as the thumb ([How to create custom layout for seekbar in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227559/how-to-create-custom-layout-for-seekbar-in-android) & [How to customize the look of a SeekBar in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187154/how-to-customize-the-look-of-a-seekbar-in-android)).

The idea is to make a SeekBar that looks like the ones in this image:

[image]

I wish to have the thumb image fit perfectly into the rounded bar when the `progress` value is set at 0 or 100 (out of 100).

In order to position the thumb correctly (i.e. not overlap the ends of the bar) I have set the  `paddingLeft` & `paddingRight` values to exactly half the width of the thumb width ([Android: Seekbar doesn't scroll all the way to end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653750/android-seekbar-doesnt-scroll-all-the-way-to-end/7727123#7727123)).

.../res/layout/main.xml:

```
<SeekBar android:id="@+id/frequency_slider"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:max="100" android:progress="0"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_no_visible_progress"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seekbar_thumb" <!-- this is an image -->
    android:background="@drawable/hos_bar" <!-- this is an image -->
    android:paddingLeft="24dp"
    android:paddingRight="24dp">
</SeekBar>
```

This works in Android 2.1.

---

In Android 2.2 this produces a different effect:

[image]

---

After further investigation (and trying this with a totally default `SeekBar` I have found that the position of the thumb image has changed from 2.1 to 2.2. My hack of changing the `paddingLeft` & `paddingRight` is not the issue.

- In 2.1, the thumb is centred around the end of the bar, with half the thumb on the bar, and half of it off the bar.
- In 2.2, the thumb is positioned within the bar, without any overlap. Hence the strange way the padding values effect the outcome. This is what I was trying to achieve, but when using a custom thumb, this effect no longer works the same way.

---

I think I need to make a custom java class to handle this type of thing. In this question ([Possible to do rounded corners in custom Progressbar progressDrawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669655/possible-to-do-rounded-corners-in-custom-progressbar-progressdrawable)), the developer uses a `ClipDrawable` in order to make a normal progress bar.

What type of drawable object would I use, and how, in order to correctly position my thumb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behaviour of thumbOffset parameter has changed between these 2 versions. ThumbOffset determines the actual offset of the thumb image, compared to the position parameter provided.

Answer (score 10):

```
seekbar.setThumbOffset(0);
```

At run-time.
Not from XML!

Solved problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
<SeekBar android:id="@+id/seek"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="73dip"
        android:max="80"
        android:progress="12"
        android:maxWidth="273dip"
        android:maxHeight="73dip"
        android:secondaryProgress="255"   
        android:background="@drawable/image2"       <!-- this is an image -->  
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/image1" <!-- this is an image -->
        android:thumb="@drawable/lock_thumb"                             
        />
```

I have tried this and it was working perfectly with 2.1 and 2.2.

In your case,try adjusting maxWidth,max and progress like i did and try removing paddings. It might help you in solving the problem.

[image]

Comment: thanks. I have updated my question. The effect that I don't want still remains (also on the standard SeekBar). I would like the thumb image to fit nicely into each rounded end of the bar, when the progress value is set to 0 or to max.

Answer (score 1):

finally found the answer, the case here is that you must use `android:thumbOffset`, but `android:thumbOffset` is **NOT** a setter for the thumb place along with the progress bar, but, it's the thumb length **from** it's beginning **to** it's center point so that the `seekbar` can adjust the thumb's center point at it's beginning point. So, if we have a thumb image with a width of **50**, the thumbOffset has to be **25** (50/2), so that the `seekbar` will adjust the **zero value** at the **pixel 25** of the thumb which will make the thumb appears to be exactly at the middle.